# When DOM shows visible state element after using .Hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unsure how to search for this, so could be a duplicate, I apologize in advance if so.

When I use the `.hide()` jquery method, I am wondering when the state will show as such. For example, this **very simplified** code doesn't seem to work

```
$('#div-to-hide').hide();

if($('#div-to-hide').is(":visible")){...}
```

How would I be able to find if the element is hidden after hiding it?

***EDIT:*** 
I have tried `.is(":visible")` and `.is(":hidden")` and neither show it as hidden. Once the method completes, and I run `$('#div-to-hide').is(":visible")` in the console, it will show as **TRUE** at that point, but not immediately after the `.hide()` is run

Comment: [:hidden](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)?

Comment: Unable to replicate: http://jsfiddle.net/ueLcfnod/. You must have some other issues in your page which are causing this.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Strange. Not sure why it's not working like Rory's JSFiddle but def doesn't see it as hidden. It's a Django form so perhaps there is something else happening?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, jquery hide basically sets `display:none;` on the element while you're checking for the `:visibility` selector which are two different things. That might be the reason for the issue you're facing right now.

Comment: Both :hidden and :visible do not work. If I check in the console after the method has run, it then shows the element as hidden

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ( $("#div-to-hide").css('display') == 'none' || $("#div-to-hide").css("visibility") == "hidden"){
// the element is hidden
}
```